# How to give space between date and time while exporting data?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

In this  date-time columns are also there  while  exporting  date-time is getting displayed like this  `2013-02-0613:18:07` without space
How to give space between date and time (i.e need to export date and  time in this format `2013-02-06 13:18:07`)  in code format given like this `=yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` I tried like this 
`yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss` but while exporting  the character T also got exported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use format string with space as you mention **yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss**

[Working Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/zaheerahmed/Sbb5Z/299/)

```
{
    field: "BirthDate",
    title: "Birth Date",
    template: '#= kendo.toString(BirthDate,"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") #'
}
```

`Window.open()` issue is that it does not take whitespaces, so you have to pass it data via URl or I hava update [Your Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zaheerahmed/5bchz/21/) may be it helps you.

Comment: thank you for reply but my requriment is while export data  space between date-time is must shown  in export file. please   check in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5bchz/18/

Comment: ya thank you for updation but grid is not disaplaying here i am geting error that  "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier "